# Add Layer to OpenLayers with Stamen "Burning Map"

Tags: javascript, openlayers, stamen-maps

as my title assert
I would like to add a new "Burning" level of type stamen to my OpenLayers map. With  others layer i.e watercolor/toner atc, it work, but not with Burning. 
My code for doing this is:

```
var stamenLayers = new ol.layer.Group({
title: 'Stamen',
layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'burning' // toner terrain toner-lite watercolor <-- this work
    })
  }),
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.Stamen({
      layer: 'terrain-labels'
    })
  })
]
});
```

Comment: It's not supported by OpenLayers because there are no burning map tiles, it's a run-time manipulation of toner lines https://hi.stamen.com/announcing-burningmap-5cccb7789150   You might be able to get a similar effect in OpenLayers by using that as the source for ol.source.Raster.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you give me an Example please for making this effect?

Comment: OpenLayers has an example based on watercolor http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/color-manipulation.html  You will probably need to use a javascript setInterval() timer and random() in calculations in the operation function to get something similar the burning map.